# Why does shadowing change the mutability of a variable in this code?

Tags: rust, immutability, shadowing

In thie following code,

```
fn main()
{
    let mename : String = String::from("StealthyPanda");
    println!("{mename}");

    let mename = displayswithhere(mename);
    println!("{mename}");

    let mename = addshere(mename);
    println!("{mename}");
}

fn displayswithhere(astring: String) -> String
{
    println!("{astring} here!");
    return astring;
}

fn addshere(mut astring : String) -> String
{
    astring.push_str(" here!");
    astring
}
```

Why isn't there an error after `mename` is shadowed and not declared as mutable when being assigned the value of `displayswithhere(mename)`? The code runs exactly as if the variable `mename` was mutable all along. I don't understand where the bug in the code, if any, is located.

Comment: Are you complaining about its change in `addshere()` or the re-assignment?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman What I'm asking is why is the `addshere(mename)` function call not causing an error, even though `mename` is not mutable? Isn't `mename` always immutable in the previous 2 declarations?

Comment: @StealthyPanda you don't mutate the `mename` variable, just have three distinct variables which have the same name (because the `let` keyword introduces new variables, see the answer below).

Answer (score 1):

When you *shadow* a variable, you create another one, distinct from the previous, but with the same name (that is just a coincidence).
The drawback is that you cannot simply refer to the former with its name any more because this names now refers to the latter.

On the example below, the functions `fn_1()` and `fn_2()` are very similar except that in `fn_1()` we still can refer directly to the original variable, but in `fn_2()` we have to find another way: we introduce a reference with a different name.

This is not related to mutability since the original variable keeps its original value all the way long.
On the other hand, `fn_3()` relies on mutability but we do not use `let` with the same name a second time, so the second assign operation is not an initialisation of a new variable but a real assign operation which will change the value of the original variable.

```rust
fn fn_1() {
    println!("~~~~~~~~");
    let my_var = 1;
    println!("my_var: {}", my_var);
    let my_other_var = 2; // creating another variable with a different name
    println!("my_other_var: {}", my_other_var);
    println!("my_var: {}", my_var);
}

fn fn_2() {
    println!("~~~~~~~~");
    let my_var = 1;
    println!("my_var: {}", my_var);
    let ref_to_my_var = &my_var;
    let my_var = 2; // creating another variable with the same name (coincidence)
    println!("my_var: {}", my_var);
    println!("ref_to_my_var: {}", ref_to_my_var);
}

fn fn_3() {
    println!("~~~~~~~~");
    let mut my_var = 1;
    println!("my_var: {}", my_var);
    my_var = 2; // changing the origianl variable, which must be mutable
    println!("my_var: {}", my_var);
}

fn main() {
    fn_1();
    fn_2();
    fn_3();
}
/*
~~~~~~~~
my_var: 1
my_other_var: 2
my_var: 1
~~~~~~~~
my_var: 1
my_var: 2
ref_to_my_var: 1
~~~~~~~~
my_var: 1
my_var: 2
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You're saying "the variable `mename`", but there's three in your `main` function. You can convince yourself of that by running the following code:

```
#![allow(unused_variables)]

struct Foo(i32);
impl Foo {
    fn new(v: i32) -> Foo {
        println!("{v}");
        Foo(v)
    }
}
impl Drop for Foo {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("{}", self.0);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo::new(0);
    let foo = Foo::new(1);
    let foo = Foo::new(2);
    println!("At this point, all three Foos are alive, each in its own variable");
}
```

Now you may ask, if I can just shadow a previous variable, what's the difference to just having it mutable? The difference should become apparent when your run this code:

```
fn main() {
    let i = 0;
    for _ in 0..2 {
        println!("{i}");
        let i = i + 1;
        println!("{i}");
    }
}
```